# Is there a way to restrict writes to master only in redis?

Tags: redis, master-slave, redis-cluster, redisson

I have a redis cluster created with master slave mode. I want to create a redisson client to access the cluster but I want to specify separate endpoints for reads and writes. Writes should go to master and reads should happen from the slaves. There is a config ***readMode*** that can I set to SLAVE to read only from slave nodes but how do I restrict writes to master only?

Answer (score 0):

In Redis, writes happen only in master nodes. So you don't need separate config to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a config readMode that can I set to SLAVE to read only from slave nodes but how do I restrict writes to master only?

Writes are executed in master nodes.

All commands are executed in the master nodes, by default: while Redis Enterprise allows for a multi-master active-active clusters, Redis (Open Source) only allows one master node and zero or more replicas per slot range. In all cases, all nodes **can** receive both read and write commands but, by default, replicas reply with a `-MOVED` redirection error along with the endpoint of the master which is believed to handle a given target key. Clients may use that information to contact the master which will actually execute the command.

With that being said, replicas can be [configured to reply to read-only commands](https://redis.io/commands/readonly/) - provided they handle the slot range of the given target key. In that context, most cluster-aware Redis clients allow to read from replicas with the goal of distributing the load - with the risk of reading stale data: Redisson manages that through the `readMode` setting and automatically deals with the aforementioned connection configuration.